# C#: escape dot character in string

Tags: c#, replace, escaping, backslash

I need to replace all ocurrences of a dot with a backslash in C# with the string "\." (escape the dot),

Wath I've tried:

```
string.Replace(".", "\\.");
string.Replace(".", @"\.");
string.Replace(".", @"\\\.");
```

all my tries finish with an even number of backslashes before the dot, that are removed automatically after.

Thanks

Comment: I need to scape it because I'm using it in a regular expresion, and  in this context it means (any character except the new line character), so I need to scape it.

Comment: The first two both work perfectly! You're probably watching the values with the Watch function from a breakpoint, but this shows backslashes with additional escapes. If you just output the string to something like the console or a file, you'll see that it works.

Comment: @PeterM. You should add this as an answer

Comment: Ok, just did that :)

Comment: I'm passing the string to a regex. When the user enters a dot ".", I want to interpret it a dot ".", so I need to scape it in the regex. But in all my tries the "." becomes a "." in the regexp, and  backslashes are removed, because after using the lines above, there is an even number of backslashes that are removed automatically.... I need to keep one backslashe before the dot in the regex

Comment: Then maybe show a bit more code please, because as Peter already said, your two first examples are completely right. The problem must be somewhere else then. And also give a example string please.

Comment: If you try this what do you see? `Console.WriteLine("|.|".Replace(".", @"\."));`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first two both work perfectly!

You're probably watching the values with the Watch function from a breakpoint, but this shows backslashes with additional escapes.

If you just output the string to something like the console or a file, you'll see that it works.

Comment: Or you can just click on the magnifying glass icon in visual studio to see the real value

Comment: I'm passing the string to a regex. When the user enters a dot ".", I want to interpret it a dot ".", so I need to scape it in the regex. But in all my tries the "." becomes a "." in the regexp, and backslashes are removed, because after using the lines above, there is an even number of backslashes that are removed

Comment: As an example, If the user enters "foo.bar", the regex must become "foo\.bar", but I get "foo.bar" after replace as above. But this matchs "foo.bar" but also "foohbar"

Comment: Console.WriteLine("foo.bar".Replace(".", "\\.")); Console.WriteLine("foo.bar".Replace(".", @"\.")); These both work fine.

Comment: I was missing something in a previous line that causes it to fail. My two first option worked, yeah. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is a method designed for this: Regex.Escape().